# Wait for validation (serverside) to complete befor insert into database

Tags: node.js, validation, asynchronous, express

I am pretty new to Node.js or Javascript in general when it comes to serverside stuff. Currently I am tring to validate some of the user input and set default values if something is wrong. Now if I run my validation the json object appears in the database befor my validation is completed.

1. The way I am doing the validation isnt maybe the best right now but if someone can explain me the behavior, I am pretty sure i can understand Javascript alot better in the future.
2. Is there a better way of doing validation (without mongoose or other ODM modules) with callbacks, middleware or should I use some async module?

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = function(app, express, todoDB, listDB, statusDB) {
var moment = require('moment');
var todoRouter = express.Router();
todoRouter.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('1');
        if (!(moment(req.body.createDate).isValid())) {
            req.body.createDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        }
        else {
            req.body.createDate = moment(req.body.createDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        }
        console.log('2');
        if (req.body.list_id == '') {
            listDB.findOne({list: 'Neu'}, function(reqdb, docs) {
                if (docs == null) {
                    listDB.insert({list: 'Neu', index: 1});
                    listDB.findOne({list: 'Neu'}, function(reqdb, docs) {
                        console.log('AnlageListID');
                        console.log(docs._id);
                        req.body.list_id = docs._id;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log('BestehendeListID');
                    console.log(docs._id);
                    req.body.list_id = docs._id;
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('3');
        if (req.body.status_id == '') {
            statusDB.findOne({status: 'offen'}, function(reqdb, docs) {
                if (docs == null) {
                    statusDB.insert({status: 'offen', index: 1});
                    statusDB.findOne({status: 'offen'}, function(reqdb, docs) {
                        console.log('AnlageStatusID');
                        console.log(docs._id);
                        req.body.status_id = docs._id;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log('BestehendeStatusID');
                    console.log(docs._id)
                    req.body.status_id = docs._id;
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('4');
        console.log('StatusID');
        console.log(req.body.status_id);
        console.log('ListID');
        console.log(req.body.list_id);
        todoDB.insert({
            todo: req.body.todo,
            createDate: req.body.createDate,
            endDate: req.body.endDate,
            discription: req.body.discription,
            comment: req.body.comment,
            list_id: req.body.list_id,
            priority_id: req.body.priority_id,
            section_id: req.body.section_id,
            user_id: req.body.user_id,
            status_id: req.body.status_id,
            company_id: req.body.company_id
        });
        res.json({message: 'TODO erfolgreich hinzugefügt!'});
    });
    return todoRouter;
};
```

... and this is the ouput:

```
1
2
3
4
StatusID

ListID

POST /api/todos 200 76.136 ms - 44
BestehendeListID
M3Xh46VjVjaTFoCM
BestehendeStatusID
48v80B4fbO87c8um
```

PS: Its a small "project" just for me learing the MEAN Stack so I am using neDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you try to sequentially execute a number of asynchronous calls and introduce checks in the code to validate if previous asynchronous calls have completed. This is not going to work in a general case because your checks may be processed before the asynchronous call goes through. It might work now and then just by chance, but I would not expect even that.

There are standard mechanisms for that. One of them is using promises, another one using `async` and yet another one if stacking up all callbacks one into another. Below I will demonstrate how to address the problem using `async`, but the same general idea applies to using promises. Check the `async` project on Github then the following part-solution will become clear:

```
var async = require("async")
async.waterfall([
    function(next) {
        listDB.findOne({list: 'Neu'}, next); // quits on error
    },
    function(doc, next) {
        if (doc) {
            return next(null, doc._id);
        } 
        statusDB.insert({status: 'offen', index: 1}, function(err) {
            if (err) return next(err); // quit on error
            statusDB.findOne({status: 'offen'}, function(err, doc) {
                    next(err, doc._id); // quits on error
            });
        });
    },
    function(id, next) {
        // do next step and so on
        next();
    }
], 
// this is the exit function: it will get called whenever an error 
// is passed to any of the `next` callbacks or when the last 
// function in the waterfall series calls its `next` callback (with
// or without an error)
function(err) {
    console.error("Error processing:", err)
});
```

Comment: Can we please stop using and pushing the `async` module? Promises are a thing now.

Comment: We cannot. This is a perfectly valid option. As I said there are a few solutions and promises is one of them.

Comment: You have got me right. I am coming from a java backgroud so I got some problem understanding asyncronous calls/callbacks. Can you give me an example for stacking up the callbacks in this case, even if its not best practice?

Comment: @Stefan This is really the options that I do not want to go through. Really, stick to promises or `async`. Promises would be what you also have in `dart` or `C#` and is probably the way to go longer term, but IMHO `async` is much easier to comprehend if all of this is new to you.

Comment: Okay, i will lock at Promises and async. Thank you very much nevertheless. If I want to understand the concept of asycronous calls and callbacks moer I have to learn more about javascript in general right? If you have any further information where I should start I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not that much JavaScript, but the general concept of asynchronous programming. Use the latter as a a search term. With promises you will cover JavaScript and a number of other languages as I mentioned. `async` is specific to node, but there might be similar cases elsewhere, I do not know. However, I think reading the `async` page will give you a really good insight into different sorts of asynchronous scenario no matter what the implementation is.